# secure authentication over LAN 802.1X

Tags: switch, hp, authentication, radius, ieee-802.1x

secure authentication over LAN
I have installed FreeRadius Version 3.0.12 server, we debian 9.4.0, and I want to secure my LAN, that means, nobody can connect to the LAN if its MAC address is not declared on the Radius server,
I also have an HP 5130 switch.
could you help me on the configuration I need to put on HP switch and FreeRadius server

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are many variables to consider when configuring LAN Authentication, but [here is a page from the HP manual on configuring 802.1x](http://h22208.www2.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/WB/15-18/5998-8152_wb_2920_asg/content/ch13s05.html), 
and [here is one from the Freeradius Wiki](https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Basic-configuration-HOWTO).

These two links should get you started.